# Creating dynamic array in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to create an array dynamically by getting user input. `range` comes as a parameter. When I try to `console.log()` that it logs the correct value of range, but when I try to use it in `const a=Array(...Array(range).keys());` it doesn't take range as correct parameter. When I hard code a number instead of range it gives a correct array. What would be the problem here??

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default  function handleSumOfMultipliers(multiplier, range) {
    console.log("range" + range)
    
    const a = Array(...Array(range).keys());
    console.log(a);

    return (
        <div></div>
    );
};
```

Comment: I tried this and it seem to work fine. What *specifically* is the issue? I don't know what "doesn't take range as correct parameter" means. Show your current output and your **desired** output

Comment: When I log a it prints as null array.

Comment: change `const a=Array(...Array(range).keys());` to `const a=Array(...Array(parseInt(range)).keys());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what I did was

```
const a = Array(...Array(parseint(range)).keys());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're forgetting to pass in a first argument, since you aren't using it in the function at the moment. So given your current function definition, if you call `handleSumOfMultipliers(5)` then inside the function, `multiplier` is 5 and `range` is undefined.

You need to given a dummy argument for the first parameter, so `handleSumOfMultipliers(null, 5)`. That way `range` will be 5 and it should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are casting the 'range' value to an int.
If I do this:

```
var a = Array('6')
a.length
```

We get 1 as the array length. User input is usually a string so maybe that's your mistake.